# Text processing for words connected by hyphen

Tags: text-processing

I have text files (*.txt) which I process, I want to find words connected by hyphen such as "drug-associated" or "drug-linked", "drug-related".

I need your help to convert the first one to "associated with drug" and the second one convert it to "linked with drug" instead. In one file I could have many of those, one time it is "associated", "linked", "related" and could have other terms.

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -pi.back -e 's/(\w+)-(\w+ed)\b/$2 with $1/g' ./*.txt
```

That's portable and would work with any system having `perl` installed.

On recent GNU systems, you can do something similar with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -ri.back 's/(\w+)-(\w+ed)\b/\2 with \1/g'
```

POSIXly:

```
for f in ./*.txt; do
  mv -i "$f" "$f.back" &&
    sed -e :1 -e 's/\([[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\)-\([[:alnum:]]\{1,\}ed\)\(\([^[:alnum:]].*\)\{0,1\}\)$/\2 with \1\3/;t1' < "$f.back" > "$f"
done
```

Comment: can i do it using sed?